Display vote closure summary in the close dialog
We recently got the asterisk feature in the Close link of questions, highlighting if we already did a closure vote, which is great.
Yet, the closure dialog could also be improved in my opinion.
Right now, that dialog fully shows existing closure vote counts as long as the voter hasn't voted yet, eventually clicking main "vote groups" in order to see what other users selected as reasons for closure.
While this may be acceptable, there's a catch: if you already voted, you cannot know:

the reason of your vote;
the reason of others' votes;

This may be trivial, but knowing how people votes (and considering how I voted) may be useful for a meta-review of our own voting practice.
As many others, I vote for closure a lot and I sometimes like to review or check the reason I did it, even though we know we cannot yet (still?!?) change our closure reason.
Sometimes I may decide to add a comment after other votes, and decide what to write as long as I can see what others did, but since the closure dialog doesn't allow going through sub-reasons, it's not really possible to do that.
I'd like to suggest the following improvements in this display mechanism:

allow going within sub section reasons, even after voting;
highlight (both in the main "page" and in sub sections) which vote reason we already gave;
display a summary of closure reasons for sub sections in the main dialog;

I mostly use StackOverflow, which only requires 3 votes for closures, but some other sites require more (usually 5, AFAIK), making this request even more relevant.

This is already requested, and already possible using keyboard shortcuts: Allow us to view the subcategories in the close dialog if already voted and what I voted for

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks, that's good to know. Yet, that request, as mine, is still valid and unanswered, even after almost 10 years: 1. even if I'm an avid user of keyboard shortcuts, that interface is certainly not immediate nor intuitive, not to mention impossible if keyboard shortcuts are disabled and completely inaccessible from touch devices; 2. since reaching that "page" is possible, allowing it from mouse/touch actions seems quite doable; 3. as pointed out in the answer about shortcuts, it still doesn't properly show which sub-section reason the user eventually voted.

@musicamante all of which is true, but this being meta, this [tag:feature-request] is still a duplicate.

Well, as a workaround, you can create a sock account, get it to 3k rep, and use it just for viewing close votes on questions you already voted to close.

@ShadowWizard No need for socks. Just use keyboard shortcuts as I point out in an answer there.
